# Node.js - Get variable from another loaded file

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have this content in `script_a.js`:

```js
let data = 'some data that can only be created once.';
let script_b = require('./script_b.js');
```

In `script_b.js`, I want to get the content of the `data` variable in `script_a.js` from when the script was originally run. I can't just recreate the variable due to the way I'm using it. How can I accomplish this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this:

script_b.js

```
module.exports = function createScriptB (data) {
  console.log('Hey I got some data')
  console.log(data)
  return data + ' and more data'
}
```

script_a.js

```
const script_b = require('./script_b.js');
const data = 'some data'

const results = script_b(data)

console.log(results) // 'some data and more data'
```

Answer (score 0):

Export a function from script_b.

Call the function from script_a.

Pass the value of `data` to the function as an argument.